# Is there a way run an HTML file in a Google Chrome "environment" without having it installed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm making a game with HTML/CSS/Javascript because it's the code I'm most comfortable with at the moment.  I'm only really doing this as an exercise in game development and plan to learn C# later.  But for now that's what I'm using, and I have a question about it.

Obviously when making a website, you want your website to be compatible with all web browsers equally.  Right now, I'm using Chrome to test/debug my game, and I've decided to develop this game with Chrome in mind.  But not everybody has Chrome, and not everyone would want to download it in order to play my game.

Is there a way to run an HTML/CSS/Javascript file in a Google Chrome "environment" without having the actual browser installed? Just it's code engine and none of the rest of the browser.

I've been reading about their V8 Javascript engine that they use in Chrome, and am wondering if that is part of the answer I'm looking for.  What I'd like to do is include this "engine" in an installer with my game files and have it install like any other game.

Hopefully this makes sense.  This may not be possible/exist, but if someone knows something I don't or an point me in the right direction, that'd be amazing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into [Node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) which essentially allows you to write desktop applications in html/css/js. When you distribute your game along with your node webkit executable, it is always run in the same environment. You can see some cool examples on their [demos and examples page](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/List-of-apps-and-companies-using-nw.js).

Comment: I'm fairly confident that is exactly what I am looking for.  Now I just need to figure out how to use it...thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to add that Node-Webkit is the perfect solution to the problem I was having.  I love it.  Thanks!  Wish I could upvote this but not enough rep...

Answer (score 1):

Usually a common path to convert web application to native desktop applications is to use a "thin" browser as app container and ship it.

A lot of current applications out there are using this trick (Spotify, Slack, etc...) and it works pretty well.
I've read of some people using the CocoonJS game engine framework and successfully ship it with this techniques.

To most famous wrappers, that I know are [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) or [electron](https://github.com/atom/electron) (AKA atom-shell).

Once you include your game in either one of those you can just "compile" it (it is not a real compile, but just to give you an idea) and ship it: with some tricks it is also possible to publish it in the Mac/Win app stores.

In case you want to focus on mobile instead, there are similar frameworks but I don't really know which are the most common.

**Note**: if you're using fancy WebGL or very advanced stuff these tools may have some issues sometimes.

Comment: I'd like that answer, despite of my preference for Electron project http://electron.atom.io/

Answer (score 0):

So essentially you want to install the JS engine to use it with any browser? In this case, the answer is: nope. Browsers act different, they don't have a standard interface, nor have this "swapping" capability in mind.

In case you'd be asking for an embedded browser inside an app... well, isn't that worse than installing Chrome? You may embed webkit/V8, but it's a hard way and you'd know programming.

So simple answer is: you'd make it compatible for at least the evergreen browsers (Chrome / Firefox mainly). Or reduce your target to webkit based only browsers (or in your case V8, i.e. Chrome, Chromium and the forks).

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your game is only for chrome, because you read V8 documentation, you can create it as an **extension**. There'sn't other way to install your JS, because browser **interpret** javascript, not compile it. And the docs you need is found at: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted